# Manage external data source locations in Excel when sharing the file across Dropbox

Tags: excel, vba

When working in Excel, sometimes we have external data sources.

In Windows, these files may be stored in a specific location such as C:\Users\Freelensia\Dropbox\data source.xls

When sharing the main file and the data source file with another person through file-sharing services such as Dropbox, the location of the data source will be changed to:

C:\Users\PeterSmith\Dropbox\data source.xls
(from the view of the Peter Smith user)

This will break the data connection in the main file when Peter  opens it. He can reset the path to the one as seen from his computer, but that will break the connection for the Freelensia user when he/she opens it from his/her end.

Is there a way to permanently fix these locations for multiple users? Such that Excel will correctly get the path when the right user opens it.

I am looking for an inherent Excel property if such a thing exists. Else VBA macros (A table with the file paths for each user, and MsgBox that ask the user to choose the user profile). Else a Windows .bat file could work as well.

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 1):

A trick to this is to move your Dropbox to C:\Dropbox for all users.

To do that, click on the Dropbox icon at the bottom-right, click the Gear Icon, Settings, Sync Tab, then you can move the folder to C:\Dropbox.

If you encounter permission errors, follow the instructions here to reset the permissions:
https://www.dropbox.com/help/desktop-web/move-dropbox-folder

Answer (score 0):

If my understanding is right when ever a different user opens/saves a file the path "C:\Users\xxxxxxx\Dropbox\data source.xls" will be same only "xxxxxxx" in the path will be varying with the active user who has logged in.
So use "Application.UserName" function to get the username and use it in the path mentioned above

Comment: Use `'s to format things like paths rather than "'s

Answer (score 0):

Excel uses relative links, even though it shows longer paths in the cells when you look at them.  This ends up meaning that if you move the file and the file(s) it is connecting to a different location then the links will still work.

If you put your main file in Dropbox\Excel\main.xlsx and then your data sources in Dropbox\Excel\Data\data sources.xlsx then I think you should be good.

I tested this with Google Drive on two different computers, taking turns opening and modifying the data source and also opening and having the main file update without any issues.

I am not positive if this would work for you in Dropbox, but I really think it should...  I am using Excel 2010, so if you are using Excel 2003 (or saving files as .xls instead of the newer .xlsx format) there is a possibility that could cause issues.